# Issues with comparing Strings in Fortran?

Tags: string, fortran

I am trying to compare a string with a set of values read into a character array. But the comparison doesn't work the way it is expected to.I have attached the code below for the check.

```
PROGRAM MWE

CHARACTER(LEN=80)       ::  FILENAME,HEADER,REMARKS
CHARACTER*6,ALLOCATABLE     ::  RESNAME(:)
INTEGER             ::  NHEADER,NATOMS,I

ALLOCATE(RESNAME(10))

FILENAME        =   "./thy_thy_wat.psf"



OPEN(10,FILE=FILENAME,STATUS='OLD',FORM='FORMATTED')

READ(10,'(A4)') HEADER
READ(10,'(B10)')
READ(10,'(T6,I4)') NHEADER

DO I=1,NHEADER
    READ(10,'(A50)') REMARKS
END DO
READ(10,'(B10)')

READ(10,'(T5,I4)') NATOMS

DO I=1,10
    READ(10,'(T19,A5)') RESNAME(I)
END DO

WRITE(*,*) RESNAME

IF (RESNAME(1) == "THY") THEN
WRITE(*,*) "YES"
END IF

END PROGRAM MWE
```

---

I can visually check that the values match, but the code doesn't give that. Any help would be appreciated 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WHOv65Lbb3PRSuE2YwMAZk1L-uqYDhXb/view?usp=sharing is the link to the file that is read in using the above code.

EDIT: I was able to solve the issue by playing around with the tabs. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: `RESNAME .EQ. "abc"`

Comment: Hello @JoopEggen, Thanks for the answer, But I think i should clarify the use-case a bit more. I have read in 2500 strings each of length 6 to the array RESNAME (which i could verify by printing out the contents). My issue is regarding comparing each of those element with a given string. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry for the lack of MWE. I will update the code to show that.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark @evets I have updated the question with a MWE by including your suggestion of using ```trim```. Looking into the references for ```trim``` i found that they cannot be assigned to a variable, because once assigned they go back to the original state.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I have updated the MWE, reproducing the bare bone part of the code that fails. I tried using ```trim``` but that didot help.

Comment: Comparison with padding to 6: `"abc   "` (with 3 spaces), when SQL CHAR(6).